# WinUi 3 In-Process Background Task (Value does not fall within the expected range)

Tags: c#, winui-3

I would like to register an in-process background task in my winui3 application. It should run every 30 minutes. At the position:

BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

An error occurs: **Value does not fall within the expected range**

Background tasks are **allowed ** for my app, but I can't get any further here.

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

namespace WinUI_3_WebView_Test
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
     
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MyWebView.DefaultBackgroundColor = Colors.White;

            RegisterBackgroundTask();

            LoadingProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += WebViewNavigationCompleted;
            
            InitializeWebView();     

        }

        private async void InitializeWebView()
        {
            await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            MyWebView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
            MyWebView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsStatusBarEnabled = false;
        }

        private void WebViewNavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public static async void RegisterBackgroundTask()
        {

            var requestStatus = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (requestStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Background Task not allowed");
            }

            else
            {
                var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                builder.Name = "My Background Trigger";
                builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
                builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserPresent));
                BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"
  xmlns:desktop4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/4"
  xmlns:iot2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10/2"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap uap3 desktop4 iot2">

  <Identity
    Name="275e701a-67bb-4e8b-845f-9bcd88bd076b"
    Publisher="CN=Test"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="275e701a-67bb-4e8b-845f-9bcd88bd076b" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>WinUI 3 WebView Test</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Test</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$"
      desktop4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true"
      iot2:SupportsMultipleInstances="true">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="WinUI 3 WebView Test"
        Description="WinUI 3 WebView Test"
        BackgroundColor="transparent"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I have already tried to create a new class and call it from there. I have increased the timer time and upgraded the project from .NET 6 to .NET 7.

Added desktop4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true" to my Package.appxmanifest

Comment: You are developing a Winui3 App not a UWP app. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680911/(winui-3)-in-process-background-task and https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4200